# I am using this library for 4 months now, but today when I tried to import automagica module it is not working properly

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to create an excel file and, fill in data automatically by using `automagica`, but it's not working. Please help me out with this issue

**Here is my code:**

```
from automagica import *

excel = Excel()


# Write to cell A1, this is column 1, row 1
excel.write_cell(1, 1, "Name")

# Write to cell, B1, this is column 2, row 1
excel.write_cell(2, 1, "Address")

# Write to cell, B1, this is column 3, row 1
excel.write_cell(3, 1, "Company")

# Write to cell A2, this is column 1, row 2
excel.write_cell(1, 2, generate_random_name())

# Write to cell A3, this is column 1, row 3
excel.write_cell(1, 3, generate_random_name())

# Write to cell A4, this is column 1, row 4
excel.write_cell(1, 4, generate_random_name())

# Write to cell A5, this is column 1, row 5
excel.write_cell(1, 5, generate_random_name())

# Write to cell A6, this is column 1, row 6
excel.write_cell(1, 6, generate_random_name())

# Write to cells B2, B3, B4, B5 and B6. This is row 2, cells 2 to 6
for i in range(2,7):
    excel.write_cell(2,i,generate_random_address())

# Write to cell range C2:C6. This is row 3, cells 2 to 6
excel.write_range('C2:C6', "Example Company")

# Declare path to save it to, in this case in the homedir with the name "awesome_excel.xlsx"
excel_save_path = home_path(r'D:\suneel\WFH work\Automagica\awesome_excel.xlsx')

# Save the worksheet, by default this is in the homedir
excel.save_as(excel_save_path)

excel.quit()

open_file(excel_save_path)
```

**The Errors:**

[image: I am getting an error when I tried to run automagica code]

[image: I installed automagica library but I couldn't able to import]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I agree it's good to know why but as a solution does it fix the problem if you simply reinstall it? `pip install automagica`

Comment: I think Netcall company made this product non-free hence removed that module from PIP. This module contains empty package, no python files inside.

Comment: According to [this history](https://pypi.org/project/automagica/#history) module was updated on Oct 16, all previous versions where removed, and current version was replaced with empty package. This kind of things are usually done when company wants to make project non-free/non-opensource, removes its sources.

Comment: @SuneelKumar Found solution how to install your module from previous github history of this project, please look into [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65356454/941531).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that inside PIP repository package was removed by Netcall company, probably they made this product non-free and removed its sources.

Only empty pip package is left, that's why module is still pip-installable but contains no sources inside. According to [this history](https://pypi.org/project/automagica/#history) package was removed on Oct 16.

But there's still github project for this PIP module, [here](https://github.com/automagica/automagica). Its sources were also removed on Oct 13. But git history wasn't deleted, I'll show next steps how to install your pip module from git previous history.

Do next steps inside command line (somewhere in temporary or writable directory):

```
git clone https://github.com/automagica/automagica/
cd automagica
git checkout master
git reset --hard ae8a184
```

This will checkout git repository at latest (ae8a184) commit just before sources removal.

Now do next command (inside checked out git repository (folder `automagica`)):

```
python -m pip install -e .
```

This will install pip module from github repository. Done!

**Note!**. You may also want to keep this checked out git repository (folder `automagica`) somewhere in your archives, I'm sure soon company will remove this git repository too if they really want to make project closed-source.

If last install command above failed for some reason, do next steps inside checked out git repository (folder `automagica`):

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

This command will build/copy sources of project to PIP wheel package. If command succeded, go to `./dist/` sub-folder, there will be file with `.whl` extension, like `Automagica-3.2.2-py3-none-any.whl` on my PC. Just install it through next pip command:

```
python -m pip install Automagica-3.2.2-py3-none-any.whl
```

Very last command worked on my Windows PC and afterwards `import automagica` worked inside Python code.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I successfully installed automagica module by following your instructions. when i tried to import in command prompts it's working fine. but in python IDLE and anaconda platforms getting same error (No module named "automagica")

Comment: @SuneelKumar That is because through command prompt you installed into global python, there is single installation of such python. But other platforms have their own virtual environment, i.e. separate python. You should read documentation on how to install into this environments from command prompt.    Another way is to create `.whl` file by instructions I gave and try to do `pip install filename.whl` from inside of those two platforms, this should solve the issue. Anyway tell me about your progress as soon as you try, finally we will solve the issue!

Comment: Hi Arty i have created Virtual environment and then i installed successfully by following your instructions. But still i am getting same error. I really don't know where i am missing.

Comment: @SuneelKumar Do next steps 1) create `.whl` file like I instructed in my answer 2) go to your platform (IDLE) 3) if it is graphical IDE then somewhere there should be something like Install Package in Menu, or maybe Python Command Prompt 4) Execute such command prompt from Menu and then there enter `python -m pip install filename.whl`. 5) Otherwise if it doesn't work you should Google something like `IDLE how to install python wheel` and follow instructions.

Comment: @SuneelKumar You can even do next thing, in your usage script do `import subprocess; subprocess.run(['python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'filename.whl'], check = True); import automagica`. This will install your package right before importing it, it should work. After first successful run you may remove subprocess call.

Comment: Thank you Arty now it's working fine.......................Thanks a lot for your time and your patience.